# pyparsing - Parse numbers with thousand separators

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

So I am making a parser, and I noticed a problem. Indeed, to parse numbers, I have:

```py
from pyparsing import Word, nums
n = Word(nums)
```

This works well with numbers without thousands separators. For example, `n.parseString("1000", parseAll=True)` returns `(['1000'], {})` and therefore works.

However, it doesn't work when I add the thousand separator. Indeed, `n.parseString("1,000", parseAll=True)` raises `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text, found ','  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)`.

How can I parse numbers with thousand separators? I don't just want to ignore commas (for example, `n.parseString("1,00", parseAll=True)` should return an error as it is not a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure pyparsing approach would use `Combine` to wrap a series of pyparsing expressions representing the different fields that you are seeing in the regex:

```
import pyparsing as pp

int_with_thousands_separators = pp.Combine(pp.Optional("-") 
                                           + pp.Word(pp.nums, max=3)
                                           + ("," + pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=3))[...])
```

I've found that building up numeric expressions like this results in much slower parse time, because all those separate parts are parsed independently, with multiple internal function and method calls (which are real performance killers in Python). So you can replace this with an expression using `Regex`:

```
# more efficient parsing with a Regex
int_with_thousands_separators = pp.Regex(r"-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*")
```

You could also use the code as posted by Jan, and pass that compiled regex to the Regex constructor.

To do parse-time conversion to int, add a parse action that strips out the commas.

```
# add parse action to convert to int, after stripping ','s
int_with_thousands_separators.addParseAction(
    lambda t: int(t[0].replace(",", "")))
```

I like using `runTests` to check out little expressions like this - it's easy to write a series of test strings, and the output shows either the parsed result or an annotated input string with the parse failure location. (`"1,00"` is included as an intentional error to demonstrate error output by `runTests`.)

```
int_with_thousands_separators.runTests("""\
    1
    # invalid value
    1,00
    1,000
    -3,000,100
    """)
```

If you want to parse real numbers, add pieces to represent the trailing decimal point and following digits.

```
real_with_thousands_separators = pp.Combine(pp.Optional("-") 
                                           + pp.Word(pp.nums, max=3)
                                           + ("," + pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=3))[...]
                                           + "." + pp.Word(pp.nums))

# more efficient parsing with a Regex
real_with_thousands_separators = pp.Regex(r"-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d+")

# add parse action to convert to float, after stripping ','s
real_with_thousands_separators.addParseAction(
    lambda t: float(t[0].replace(",", "")))

real_with_thousands_separators.runTests("""\
    # invalid values
    1
    1,00
    1,000
    -3,000,100
    1.

    # valid values
    1.732
    -273.15
    """)
```

Comment: Some of the example strings passed to `runTests` (such as `"1,00"`, or the real numbers with no decimal parts) are intentional errors, to demonstrate `runTests` error output. I've edited to show example strings that are expected to fail.

Answer (score 2):

As you are dealing with strings in the first place, you could very well use a regular expression on it to ensure that it is indeed a number (thousand sep including). If it is, replace every comma and feed it to the parser:

```
import re
from pyparsing import Word, nums
n = Word(nums)

def is_number(number):
    rx = re.compile(r'^-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*$')
    if rx.match(number):
        return number.replace(",", "")
    raise ValueError

try:
    number = is_number("10,000,000")
    print(n.parseString(number, parseAll=True))
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number")
```

With this, e.g. `1,00` will result in `Not a number`, see a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CDyK8o/2).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Can't we make it directly using `pyparsing`? Also, we could use `re.compile(r'^-*\d+(?:,\d{3})*$')` instead of `re.compile(r'^-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*$')` for multiple negative signs.

Comment: @TheOneMusic: Glad to be of any help. Indeed I have never use `pyparsing` myself, my favourite one is [`parsimonious`](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious).

Comment: Can it parse numbers with thousand separators?

Comment: If you take off the '^' and '$' anchors (which might confuse pyparsing if scanning for a number as part of a larger expression), you can use that re to build yourself a pyparsing Regex, and then incorporate it into a larger expression.

Comment: @PaulMcG: I know you are the actual author of `pyparsing`. Feel free to edit my answer or provide one on your own to include your solution.

Comment: I've no desire to snipe your check mark points from you - I always appreciate and encourage others pitching in on pyparsing questions. I wrote pyparsing because I was terrible at regular expressions, but in only the 19 years since, I've actually gotten fairly good at them.

Comment: @PaulMcG: It is not about the reputation but for the learning, isn't it. I'll even sleep well with -15 rep...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well what you mean with "numbers with thousands of separators".

In any case, with pyparsing you should define the pattern of what you want to parse.

In the first example pyparse works well just because you defined n as just a number, so:

```
n = Word(nums)
print(n.parseString("1000", parseAll=True))
['1000']
```

So, if you want to parse "1,000" or "1,00", you should define n as:

```
n = Word(nums) + ',' + Word(nums)

print(n.parseString("1,000", parseAll=True))
['1', ',', '000']

print(n.parseString("1,00", parseAll=True))
['1', ',', '00']
```

Comment: That is not what I want. I do not want to parse `1,00` as it is not a number. Also, this only works with numbers with one thousand separator only, but it won't work with `1,000,000` for example, as this number has two thousand separators

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with a regex solution, kind of late:

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums
import re

n = Word(nums)

def parseNumber(x):
    parseable = re.sub('[,][0-9]{3}', lambda y: y.group()[1:], x)
    return n.parseString(parseable, parseAll=True)

print(parseNumber("1,000,123"))
```

Comment: @Jan it is meant to raise an exception in that case. It's an invalid number. Read the OP.